# Dictionary in Json C#

Tags: json, dictionary

Here is how I call the method:

```
{"email":"xxx@hotmail.com","json":{"some1":"some1", "id":1},"yyy":"yyy"}
```

And my method has these parameters:

```
MyMethod(string email, Dictionary<string, object> json, string timestamp){...}
```

And when I call it with the above mentioned parameters, the method is being called but 'json' doesn't contain nothing. Its count is 0. Why is this happening? How to solve it?

Comment: it would help if you show us *how* you call the method...

Comment: @epoch I call it via Fiddler. Those are the parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default JSON serializer does not support this out of the box, however [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) and the `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer` support this, check the answers to a similar question:
[How can I deserialize JSON to a simple Dictionary<string,string> in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207731/how-can-i-deserialize-json-to-a-simple-dictionarystring-string-in-asp-net)

JSON.NET will be the default json serializer for ASP.NET 4.5 WebAPI, so you can expect it to be shipped with ASP.NET + get support from MS for it.

**UPDATE**
In order to let ASP.NET bind the model properly you need a custom model binder:

```
 public class DictionaryModelBinder : IModelBinder
  {
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
      var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
      var value = controllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["json"];
      return serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(value));
    }
  }
```

And add the new model binder to the Application model binders in the Application_Start method:

```
  protected void Application_Start()
  {          
    ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof (Dictionary<string, object>), new DictionaryModelBinder());
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
  }
```

Comment: @But the parameter json doesn't contain anything.

Comment: you need to change the type, the method signatiure needs to look like this: `MyMethod(string email, string json, string timestamp)`, afterwards use the code provided in the other answers

Comment: then you need a custom model binder, I have updated the answer to include some sample code

Comment: This isn't ASP.NEt. It's Wcf service.